# NestJS Testing service using MikroORM

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, mikro-orm

I have a service that works properly with my MySQL database using MikroORM.  The issue I have though is trying to make a test.  The issue is creating the basic test just to get the service created.

I have a sample TestService below, which has a TestEntity defined in the test file to be able to test the code.

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { Entity, EntityRepository, Property, Unique } from '@mikro-orm/core';
import { getRepositoryToken } from '@mikro-orm/nestjs';
import { TestService } from './mikro-orm.service';

@Entity()
export class TestEntity {
    @Property() @Unique() public Code: number;
    @Property({ length: 20 }) @Unique() public Description: string;

    constructor(Code: number, Description: string) {
        this.Code = Code;
        this.Description = Description;
    }
}

describe('TestService', () => {
    let service: TestService<TestEntity>;
    let serviceRepository: EntityRepository<TestEntity>;

    const REPOSITORY_TOKEN = getRepositoryToken(TestEntity);
    beforeEach(async () => {
        const mockDataRepository = {
            provide: REPOSITORY_TOKEN,
            useValue: {
                findAll: jest.fn(),
                findOne: jest.fn(),
            },
        };

        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [TestService, mockDataRepository],
        }).compile();

        service = module.get<TestService<TestEntity>>(TestService);
        serviceRepository = module.get<EntityRepository<TestEntity>>(REPOSITORY_TOKEN);
    });

    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(service).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(serviceRepository).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Without trying to mock the calls, etc., I am just trying to get the basic creation tested. However, when running the test script above, I get the following error:

```
TestService › should be defined

    Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TestService (?). Please make sure that the argument EntityRepository at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.

    Potential solutions:
    - If EntityRepository is a provider, is it part of the current RootTestModule?
    - If EntityRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RootTestModule?
      @Module({
        imports: [ /* the Module containing EntityRepository */ ]
      })

      at TestingInjector.lookupComponentInParentModules (../../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:231:19)
      at TestingInjector.resolveComponentInstance (../../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:184:33)
      at TestingInjector.resolveComponentInstance (../../node_modules/@nestjs/testing/testing-injector.js:16:45)
      at resolveParam (../../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:106:38)
          at async Promise.all (index 0)
      at TestingInjector.resolveConstructorParams (../../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:121:27)
      at TestingInjector.loadInstance (../../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:52:9)
      at TestingInjector.loadProvider (../../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:74:9)
          at async Promise.all (index 3)
      at TestingInstanceLoader.createInstancesOfProviders (../../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:44:9)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
```

**EDIT**: The constructor of the service:

```
constructor(private readonly DataEntity: EntityRepository<T_Entity>) {}
```

Comment: Can you show what the `TestService` constructor looks like here? Most likely, there should be a `getRepositoryToken()` method exposed by `MikroORM` that should be what is matching up to the `@InjectRepository()`

Comment: I believe that is my issue.  If I remove it from the constructor, I can then set it in the code using the service, my adding a setter.  I believe my issue is going to be how to add the repository as it is a generic, not a set value.  My service using TestService gets the @InjectRepository().